# Loop to repeat a method 3 times if condition fails

Tags: c#

Im looking for a simple way, to repeat a method, when an element(selector) for example a button on a webpage cant be found.

My idea or my plan is, that:

1. If the selector can be found, the method is done
2. If the selector **cant** be found, it should repeat the "FindElement" method up to maximal 3 times
3. If the selector **cant** be found after the third try, it should give me an output message of the "NoSuchElementException e"

I tried different loops and i always end up having endless loops like in the code below.

```
    public static void FindElement(IWebDriver webDriver, string selector)
    {
        int maxTries = 0;

        try
        {
            webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(selector));
            Console.WriteLine("Element found.");
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            if (maxTries !> 3 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Element, not found. Retrying.");
                maxTries++;
                FindElement(webDriver, selector);
            } 
            else 
            {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's not an endless loop, that is an infinite recursion ... use an actual loop.

Comment: Also `maxTries !> 3` [does not do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) what you think it does. Replace with `maxTries <= 3`.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden C# dev of nearly 20 years here, and while I knew it was wrong, I can't actually work out what it does. lol. Surely it's a compile error, no?

Comment: @NeilBarnwell: It took me a while too, it is the C#8 [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving).

Answer (score 2):

What a coincidence: Just a few days ago I wrote a short helper method to separate "retry logic" from "business logic".

```
private T Retry<T>(Func<T> action, int maxRetryCount, int waitMilliseconds,
                   Func<Exception, bool> retryCondition)
{
    var retryCount = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            // If the action was successful (no exception thrown),
            // we can leave the method.
            return action();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) when (retryCount < maxRetryCount && retryCondition(ex))
        {
            retryCount += 1;
            Thread.Sleep(waitMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Which would be called as follows in your case:

```
var element = Retry(() => webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(selector)),
                    2, 0,
                    ex => ex is NoSuchElementException);
```

Whenever the maximum number of retries is reached, the exception is not caught any more (the `when` condition fails) and can be caught by your regular exception handling logic instead.

Since you are trying to automate a web browser, you might consider passing something else than `0` as `waitMilliseconds`, to give the browser time to render the elements that are still missing.

Comment: I like this way more than any other, because showing how we can put a function in function's parameters (didn't even know it was possible). Same as the "when...". The sleep also sems important here.

Comment: Excellent Answer, just wanted to mention that if you have more requirements like this, you might be interested in [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the `maxTry` outside of your function?

```
int maxTry=3;
string errorMessage="";
for(int i=0;i<maxTry;i++)
{
    try
    {
         FindElement(webDriver,selector)
         errorMessage="";
         break;
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        errorMessage=e;
    }
}
if(errorMessage!="")
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Element found.");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For recursion, you should pass the amount of remaining iterations to the function, and decrement it for each iteration.

```
public static void FindElement(IWebDriver webDriver, string selector, int iterations = 3)
{
    iterations--;

    if (iterations < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Max iterations passed, exiting")
        return;
    } 

    try
    {
        webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath(selector));
        Console.WriteLine("Element found.");
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Element not found. Retrying.");
        FindElement(webDriver, selector, iterations);
    }
}
```